# Ember Data - Category Counts For All Posts

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to work through a scenario where you have a blog with a number of posts, and each post has a variable number of categories associated with it.

I'm trying to understand how I could display a list of categories with the total number of times they are used in all posts.

Here's a JS Bin of what I'm working through:

http://jsbin.com/AyAGeVI/2/edit

Under each post is a list of associated categories in grey. The blue categories need to show how many times each category is used.

I'm stumped on how to even start this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass the current model into into the categories controller as the model, then use that model to sum up the tags.

```
{{render 'categories' model}}
```

Here's a verbose example showing it

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  categoryCount: function(){
    var items = {},
        result =[],
        categories = this.getEach('categories');

    categories.forEach(function(catGroups){
      catGroups.forEach(function(cat){
        var catName = cat.get('name'),
            curCount = items[catName],
            nextCount = curCount ? ++curCount : 1; 

        items[catName] = nextCount;
      });
    });

    for( var i in items ) {
      if (items.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var item = {};
        item.name = i;
        item.value = items[i];
        result.push(item);
      }
    } 
    return result;

  }.property('model.@each.categories')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oMIcIco/1/edit